# Bash script to find files with a given string in their names, and then interactively delete them

Tags: shell-script, find

I need to make a `bash` script that takes two arguments, one is the string to search for in the filenames and the next one is the file path to search in. Next it needs to go through one matching file at a time and print it out, then prompt the user if they want to delete it or not.

An example of it would be:

```
./scriptName.sh foo /path/to/directory/

/path/to/directory/foo.txt

Delete this? (y/n)

user input

/path/to/directory/foop.txt

Delete this? (y/n)

user input

etc...
```

I originally tried

```
find $2 -type f -name "*$1*" -print
```

and

```
find $2 -type f -name "*$1*" -delete
```

Where `$1` is the first argument and `$2` are the second argument of the script.

This worked until I realized that it had to list each found file separately and prompt to delete them which is a bit of problem since the previous two lines of code just deletes all the matching files at once.

Answer (score 2):

You could either use `-ok` to execute `rm` on the found pathnames, or use `-exec` to execute `rm -i`.

This shows short examples of each, and assumes that `$searchpath` is the search path and `$pattern` is the *final* name pattern (e.g. `"*$1*"`).

Using `-ok`:  The `-ok` action of `find` is similar to `-exec`, but it asks the user for confirmation first, before executing the given utility. We use it to execute `rm` on each found pathname individually.

```
find "$searchpath" -type f -name "$pattern" -ok rm {} \;
```

Using `rm -i`: This would make the `rm` utility itself ask for confirmation before removing a file.  We can use this on batches of pathnames.

```
find "$searchpath" -type f -name "$pattern" -exec rm -i {} +
```

---

You could obviously implement your own prompting too.  Here's a `bash` script that prompts for deletion of the single file at `"$pathname"`:

```
read -p "Delete the file at $pathname? y/[n]: "
[[ "$REPLY" == [yY]* ]] && rm "$pathname"
```

Calling this from `find` for batches of pathnames:

```
find "$searchpath" -type f -name "$pattern" -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        read -p "Delete the file at $pathname? y/[n]: "
        [[ "$REPLY" == [yY]* ]] && rm "$pathname"
    done' bash {} +
```

If the user replies with a string starting with an upper or lower cased `y`, the file will be deleted.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score -2):

```
pattern=$1
dir=$2

for file in $(find ${dir} -type f -name "*${pattern}*")
do
  /bin/rm -i ${file}
done
```

Basically you are looping through the files the `find` command returns and `rm -i` command is asking you a `y/n` question to delete the file or not. I think it is what you are looking for but if not, let people know what your exact need is for further help.

Comment: thank you for your help, I'm sure I can figure it out myself but the major part of this is the prompt to the user to decide whether or not to delete the file. Can I put this between the do done?

Comment: `rm -i` command i.e., interactive `rm` is there for this exact purpose. You do not need to do anything, unless you want a totally different verbiage. If this is the case, put your message before `rm` command and test if the user said yes or not using conditionals. Just create a dummy file and run `rm -i dummyfile` command to see how it works

Comment: Don’t do `for file in $(find …); do …`; do `find "$dir" -type f -name "*${pattern}*" -exec rm -i {} +`. Note that `$dir` should be quoted (in double quotes); putting it in braces accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @G-Man: putting variables in between `{ }` is the proper way to do, and at the most unexpected moment, they save you a lot of headache, because you did not think how a variable changes or not changes when it is not quoted and comes next to some other variable or keyword. You are entitled to your opinion how to handle a case like this but please do not spread wrong beliefs of your like _braces accomplish nothing_

Comment: @G-Man is correct.  in this particular case, the braces, while harmless, do nothing of any use, but double-quoting the variables would protect against embedded spaces and other problem characters.   He's also correct about not using `for file in $(find ...)`.  Use `find ... -exec rm -i {} +` as he suggested or `find ... | while IFS= read file ; do rm -i "$file" ; done`.  The former (`-exec rm`) works for all files, even those with newlines in the filename, whereas the second (`while` loop) works for all filenames except those with newlines.  These are not matters of opinion, they are facts.

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: I didn’t mean to say that enclosing variable names in braces never does anything.  Of course, it sometimes does something beneficial — in fact, `"*${pattern}*"` is an example (albeit a flawed one) of what it’s good for — and it’s not a bad habit to get into.  But it doesn’t accomplish anything when used on a free-standing variable, like `${file}` in your answer.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  On the other hand, all shell variable references (including `$(…)`) should always be quoted (unless you have a good reason not to); and doing that is a ***much*** more important habit to get into.  And thinking that enclosing variable names in braces gives you the same sort of protection that double quotes give you is wrong, and a very dangerous way of thinking.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You say, “at the most unexpected moment, they (braces) save you a lot of headache …”  I’m going to disagree with that.  If you use `$foo_bar` (or even `"$foo_bar"`) when you meant `${foo}_bar` (or `"${foo}_bar"` or `"$foo"_bar`), i.e., you want the value of `$foo` + the literal string `_bar`, and you do any testing, you will discover your error immediately.  But if you use `$foo` (or even `${foo}`) when you meant `"$foo"` (or `"${foo}"`), *that* error will cause you a lot of headache at the most unexpected moment; when you encounter a filename with special character(s) in it.